# How to solve Half Practice Problem from CS50's?

Tags: c, math, cs50

I'm struggling to solve this problem from CS50's introduction to computer science. It might seem simple but I still couldn't get it why it's not working properly.

So, I have to prompt a bill amount (type float) before tax and tip, calcule tax and tip using its percentage and then add them all and split it in two. The user prompt is a bill amount (type float) before taxes, tip and tax percentages. I have to complete a given function as shown below.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

**And we should have**

`Bill before tax and tip: 12.50`

`Sale Tax Percent: 8.875`

`Tip percent: 20`

`You will owe $8.17 each!`

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/

**What I've been trying**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");
    float bill = bill_amount;
    float tax = tax_percent / 100;
    int tip = tip_percent / 100;

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill, tax, tip));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float bill_after_tax = bill * tax + bill;
    float bill_after_tax_tip = bill_after_tax * tip + bill_after_tax;
    float split = bill_after_tax_tip / 2;
    return split;
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: If the task is to complete the function `half`, why are you changing the code in the function `main`?

Comment: @Dúthomhas It was supposed to be only *

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It doesn't recognize when I declare bill, tax, tip in function half. I'm trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: Programming is tough in large part because it requires you to be exceedingly _exact_ with stuff. Like counting ants. Or rice. Mess up and some ant is not going to be happy and the whole of ant society collapses.  (Which is to say, the ants compiling your program will not like it.)

Comment: I’m not sure I see the error where those values should not be passed correctly to `half()`. What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is to complete the function `half`, not to make changes in the function `main`. Therefore, the changes you made to the function `main` violate the constraints of the task.

For this reason, you should divide `tax` and `tip` by `100` in the function `half`, not in the function `main`:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float bill_after_tax = bill * ( tax / 100.0 ) + bill;
    float bill_after_tax_tip = bill_after_tax * ( tip / 100.0 ) + bill_after_tax;
    float split = bill_after_tax_tip / 2;
    return split;
}
```

Note that it is important to write `( tip / 100.0 )` instead of `( tip / 100 )`, because the former is a floating-point division, whereas the latter is an integer division, which always has an integer result. This is because `tip` and `100` are both of type `int`. For example, `( 20 / 100.0 )` evaluates to the floating-point number `0.2`, whereas `( 20 / 100 )` evaluates to the integer `0`. You want the result to be `0.2`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of tip should be float since you are dividing it by 100 which results in a decimal number.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");
    float bill = bill_amount;
    float tax = tax_percent / 100.0;
    float tip = tip_percent / 100.0;

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill, tax, tip));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, float tip)
{
    float bill_after_tax = bill \* tax + bill;
    float bill_after_tax_tip = bill_after_tax \* tip + bill_after_tax;
    float split = bill_after_tax_tip / 2;
    return split;
}
```

Comment: In light of your comment preceding the code, `float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)` is a bit of a let down...